# What does the second number in Pester's coverage % mean?

Tags: powershell, pester

When I run pester I get this output

`Covered 100% / 75%. 114 analyzed Commands in 1 File`

What does the 75% mean? I haven't been able to find it anywhere in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the value of `$PesterPreference.CodeCoverage.CoveragePercentTarget.Value`, i.e the minimum amount of test coverage you want to achieve. This is set to 75% by default.

It's mentioned on the page describing `New-PesterConfiguration`:

- https://pester-docs.netlify.app/docs/commands/New-PesterConfiguration

> CoveragePercentTarget: Target percent of code coverage that you want
> to achieve, default 75%.   Default value: 75

But it was quite hard to figure out, and it could do with being added to the documentation page about test coverage. I ended up searching through the source code and found that the message you listed is output here:

- https://github.com/pester/Pester/blob/1515194f4868f6aaae82d7d376a8a776afe0ebf4/src/functions/Output.ps1

```
CoverageMessage   = 'Covered {2:0.##}% / {5:0.##}%. {3:N0} analyzed {0} in {4:N0} {1}.'
```

Which is populated with values here:

```
$coverageMessage = $ReportStrings.CoverageMessage -f $command, $file, $executedPercent, $totalCommandCount, $fileCount, $PesterPreference.CodeCoverage.CoveragePercentTarget.Value
```